# How to set Done key in keyboard in swift-language?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

In objective-C I use this code for adding Done key to keyboard

```
[textField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
```

How to set Done key in keyboard in swift-language?

in swift this code gives error 'not have a member named setReturnKeyType'

```
textField.setReturnKeyType
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You directly assign the value to the returnKeyType property.

```
textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done
```

In Swift, you access the individual items in the enum with a dot syntax. This can also be shortened further to:

```
textField.returnKeyType = .Done
```

Comment: set this line dose not set done button in keyboard can help me?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like that:

```
textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done
```

Answer (score 2):

None Code based approach:

Select your text field view from the main storyboard view controller in which it is embedded in. If you look on the Utilities view, under it's Attributes Inspector, there will be a long list of attributes. Under the Text Field heading you will se various settings such as font, alignment, placeholder etc. As you look down from there, you will come up on 6 drop down lists, titled "capitalization" through "Return Key". When you click on the list titled "return Key", you will see a list of return keys including "Search", "Yahoo","Route" etc. From this list select the "Done" keyword. That should do the trick [Image of what this looks like in XCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UKwD.png)

Also From apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html):

"You configure the attributes of the keyboard directly through the text objects of your app. The UITextField and UITextView classes both conform to the UITextInputTraits protocol, which defines the properties for configuring the keyboard. Setting these properties programmatically or in the Interface Builder inspector window causes the system to display the keyboard of the designated type."